# Is there a way to allow 'this' attribute or 'this other' attribute, but not both?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am trying to allow for two attribute values for one element.  This is how I have it done now, but I only want to allow 1 of the 2, but not both.

```
<contact phoneH="cell">8025550000</contact>
<contact phoneW="work"> 8025550094</contact>
```

I am looking to be able to do something like this:

```
<xsd:attribute name="phoneH|phoneW" type="xsd:string" />
```

Is there a way to do use the restriction element with attributes?

Thanks,
Levi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with W3C xsd.

An alternative would be making phoneH and phoneW subelements of contact, and using `xs:choice` to limit the user to one or the other subelement.

Comment: Ok.  I had actually just read about the second option and I would normally just switch over and do it that way but this is part of some non-graded homework so I didn't want to deviate too far from the requirements.  But yeah, choice is a good alternative for a normal scenario.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that attribute constraint is possible with XML Schema.

You can apply additional validation mechanisms (i.e. [schematron](http://www.schematron.com)) or use a different schema implementation (i.e. [Relax-NG](http://www.relaxng.org/))

http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200107/msg00070.html

> Unfortunately you can't do this with
>   W3C XML Schema. As I see it you have
>   two options:
>
> 1) Change to a different schema
>   dialect (I think RELAX-NG support this
>   functionality) 
>   2) Express you
>   co-constraint using an embedded
>   schematron rule
>
> These constraints can be validated
>   with the new Schematron Validator from
>   Topologi. The tool is free and can be
>   downloaded from www.topologi.com.

Comment: Ok, I will have to do some reading on both of those.  I know at some point this semester my XML teacher is going to go over them, but it might be good to have some basics down before that.